# Does CustomRetryPolicy use the same configured consistency level for retries?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have implemented CustomRetry with Cassandra4.X and has configured as follows

```
ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder programmaticBuilder = \
  DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
    .withClass(DefaultDriverOption.RETRY_POLICY_CLASS, CustomRetry.class)
```

CustomRetry has the following implementations

```
onReadTimeout
onWriteTimeout
```

The write query is executed as follows where writeCL is EACH_QUORUM

```
boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(writeCL);
```

The error in the application log is as follows

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException: \
  Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE \
  (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)`
```

Why is it complaining about LOCAL_ONE ?
Also how do i make sure retry is getting triggered ?

Comment: Looks like its not a retry use case(not sure if retry is being triggered), but the query is getting executed with LOCAL_ONE even if we are setting up consistency as "EACH_QUORUM" on bound statement.  We use different consistencies for Read and Write and it cannot be set during session initialization . How do we maintain two d   ifferent consistencies ? ConsistencyLevel writeCL = DefaultConsistencyLevel.valueOf(cassandraConfig.getCatalogCassandraWriteConsistency());
        try {
            boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(writeCL);

Answer (score 0):

The default built-in retry policy (`DefaultRetryPolicy`) in the Cassandra Java driver retries using the same consistency level whether the CL was configured for a single statement or global setting.

The other built-in retry policy `ConsistencyDowngradingRetryPolicy` (NOT recommended) will downgrade the consistency if the operation has a better chance of succeeding.

Since you are using a custom retry policy, the behaviour will depend on what you have programmed in your policy. Since you haven't provided the code, it is impossible to know what your policy does.

Having said that, in my experience developers and operators don't spend enough time investigating and gathering evidence so they often confuse the operation in log files with unrelated operations. In your case the operation that used `LOCAL_ONE` is most likely unrelated to the code you are troubleshooting. Cheers!

Comment: Erick Ramirez , Lets park the retry question for now.  The thing I observed is Driver is not using the consistency that i set at the  statement level , instead its using the default one.  I am using different consitencies for read and write and cannot set this globally at the session level. We were able to do the same with Cassandra 3.X but Cassandra 4.0 isnot working this way  . This is how i set my consistencyt - boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(writeCL);